# Java Hashmap Problems.

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

The tester on my school's compsci website is not working, so I am currently unable to test my code. There are two areas in the code that I am somewhat confused about, and would really appreciate some input. So the code I have written is as follows.

```
public int countPairs(String[] words) {
     Set <String> pairs = new HashSet<String>();
     int noOfPairs= 0;
     for (String word:words){
         Map noOfOccurencesOfEachLetter= getMap(word);
         ArrayList<Integer> valuesFromFirstWord = new ArrayList<Integer>(noOfOccurencesOfEachLetter.values());
         Collections.sort(valuesFromFirstWord);
         java.util.List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
         list.remove(word);
         String[] oneLessWord = list.toArray(new String[words.length-1]);
         for(String secondWord:oneLessWord){
             Map secondNoOfOccurencesOfEachLetter = getMap(secondWord);
             ArrayList<Integer> valuesFromSecondWord = new ArrayList<Integer>(secondNoOfOccurencesOfEachLetter.values());
             Collections.sort(valuesFromSecondWord);
             if (valuesFromFirstWord.equals(valuesFromSecondWord)){
                 noOfPairs+=1;
             }

         }


     }
     return noOfPairs/2;
  }
```

This code is meant to give me the number of isomeric pairs of words that exist in the array(words) given. I have written a method called `getMap` outside which basically creates a map where the keys are the letters of the alphabet that are contained in the word, and the value is the number of occurrences of that letter in the word.

Now my questions are:

1) Is this line valid Java code?

```
ArrayList<Integer> valuesFromFirstWord = new ArrayList<Integer>
(noOfOccurencesOfEachLetter.values());
```

Or do I need to create my list of the values contained in the dictionary by some loop usage?

2) In order that I do not include the same word in the second for loop, I created a new array called oneLessWord that has all the elements of words except for the word that the initial for loop is going over. Do these three lines of code do that?

```
java.util.List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));

list.remove(word);

String[] oneLessWord = list.toArray(new String[words.length-1]);
```

I would appreciate any feedback.

Thanks a lot,
Junaid

Comment: "The tester on my school's compsci website is not working, so I am currently unable to test my code" SO is not a substitute for a compiler.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP does not have the enthusiasm or professinalism to check whether their code compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)  Is this line valid Java code? Or do I need to create my list of the values contained in the dictionary by some loop usage?

This is just fine. [`Map#values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) returns a `Collection`, and `ArrayList` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) that allows you to pass a `Collection` to it.

> 2)  In order that I do not include the same word in the second for loop, I created a new array called oneLessWord that has all the elements of words except for the word that the initial for loop is going over. Do these three lines of code do that?

Yes they do exactly that.